# MySQL crashes frequently on a Windows server

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have been facing an issue with MySQL crashes since last week. I don't know what exactly is happening. When I look at the Windows logs, I see the following error message:

```
Faulting application name: mysqld.exe, version: 5.6.10.0, time stamp: 0x510bcc9d
Faulting module name: mysqld.exe, version: 5.6.10.0, time stamp: 0x510bcc9d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000004ab6e0
Faulting process id: 0xb78
Faulting application start time: 0x01cfa4fe2f753615
Faulting application path: C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe
Faulting module path: C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe
Report Id: db3353ec-11bd-11e4-8fe2-0050569f52a2
```

I also had a look at the error log but it is not providing me the exact reason for the crash. Below is the message I found at crash time in my error log file.

```
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2014-07-23 09:37:38 8934 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 366.0M
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 4950357139
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.10-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
2014-07-23 09:50:41 28704 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave. Statement: DELETE  s.* FROM mt_cmn_schedules as s,mt_cmn_prescription p   where    p.FKYS_COMBO_ID='5740'  and p.FKYS_COMBO_ID=s.FKYS_MED_ID   and p.DT_CUT_DATE < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()  and s.DT_PLANNED_DATE_TIME > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and p.BOL_STATUS=0
2014-07-23 09:57:41 28704 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave. Statement: DELETE  s.* FROM mt_cmn_schedules as s,mt_cmn_prescription p   where    p.FKYS_COMBO_ID='3060'  and p.FKYS_COMBO_ID=s.FKYS_MED_ID   and p.DT_CUT_DATE < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()  and s.DT_PLANNED_DATE_TIME > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and p.BOL_STATUS=0
2014-07-23 09:57:41 28704 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave. Statement: DELETE  s.* FROM mt_cmn_schedules as s,mt_cmn_prescription p   where    p.FKYS_COMBO_ID='5700'  and p.FKYS_COMBO_ID=s.FKYS_MED_ID   and p.DT_CUT_DATE < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()  and s.DT_PLANNED_DATE_TIME > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and p.BOL_STATUS=0
2014-07-23 09:57:41 28704 [Warning] Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave. Statement: DELETE  s.* FROM mt_cmn_schedules as s,mt_cmn_prescription p   where    p.FKYS_COMBO_ID='5743'  and p.FKYS_COMBO_ID=s.FKYS_MED_ID   and p.DT_CUT_DATE < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()  and s.DT_PLANNED_DATE_TIME > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and p.BOL_STATUS=0
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Warning] option 'innodb-autoextend-increment': unsigned value 67108864 adjusted to 1000
2014-07-23 10:14:21 e018 InnoDB: Warning: Using innodb_additional_mem_pool_size is DEPRECATED. This option may be removed in future releases, together with the option innodb_use_sys_malloc and with the InnoDB's internal memory allocator.
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 366.0M
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Log scan progressed past the checkpoint lsn 4951130974
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2014-07-23 10:14:21 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2014-07-23 10:14:23 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages 
2014-07-23 10:14:23 79040 [Note] InnoDB: from the doublewrite buffer...
InnoDB: Doing recovery: scanned up to log sequence number 4951130994
InnoDB: Last MySQL binlog file position 0 466321, file name MWCAT01T-bin.000057
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 4951130994
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] Recovering after a crash using MWCAT01T-bin
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] Starting crash recovery...
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] Crash recovery finished.
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] IPv6 is available.
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
2014-07-23 10:14:24 79040 [Note] C:\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.6.10-log'  socket: ''  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Can anyone please help in fixing this issue?

Answer (score 3):

There is a bug on 5.6.10 version, fixed on 5.6.11
Microsoft Windows: In Shared Memory mode, the MySQL Server could crash when receiving requests from multiple threads. (Bug #13934876)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.6/en/news-5-6-11.html

Answer (score -2):

There is another bug in MySQL which causes mysql to crash every time a flush tables is performed if you are using federated tables.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47525

There's a MySQL setting called flush_time and it defaults to 1800 (30 minutes) on Windows.  This causes mysql to crash every 30 minutes.  Since this setting is only recommended for low resource boxes, as long as you have a fairly decent box, **the solution is to set flush_time = 0 in my.ini**.

On 'nix boxes this value already defaults to 0 so this is a Windows issue only.

Comment: The bug you are linking to is related to version 5.1.39 while this question is about 5.6. Also, the ticket is marked as closed. Are you sure your suggestion is relevant for this question?

Comment: The bug also exists in 5.5.61 so there's a good chance it also exists in 5.6.  Regardless this may help others who are searching for reasons why their version of MySQL is crashing on Windows.

Comment: Wilson, I had purposely not said "federated engine" because I believe the bug only rears its ugly head when you actually select from a federated table, and not merely if the federated engine is enabled.

Comment: The bug is related to federated tables, whereas if looking at the log posted by the OP, his instances isn't running the federated plugin. `2014-07-23 09:37:38 28704 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.`

Comment: That's true but if anybody is experiencing this bug they likely won't know that it's related to the federated table so they won't specifically search using that keyword and may end up on a more generic question like this one.  That's why I think it's useful to post this answer here.